# Multiple ingress-nginx-controller replicas

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, ingress-nginx

I've installed [Ingress-Nginx Controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) using the [ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/main/charts/ingress-nginx) helm chart.

Is it possible to have 2 or more `ingress-nginx-controller` Pod replicas ?
I noticed that [in the helm chart](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/charts/ingress-nginx/values.yaml#L365), there is even an option for auto-scaling.
I currently only have one replica, but I would like to do something like this:

```
$ kubectl scale deploy ingress-nginx-controller --replicas=3
```

I'm not sure if it will work as expected, especially with caching, cookies, sessions etc.

Comment: It seems to me that you already found your solutions: provide values in the helm chart or scale it explicitly. There is also a value for the number of replicas (https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installing-nic/installation-with-helm/#configuration): controller.replicaCount. I haven't tried, but it sounds like worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

- Yes, you can run multiple NGINX Ingress Controllers, each handling a different set of configuration resources by following this [nginx ingress controller doc](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/running-multiple-ingress-controllers/#:%7E:text=Using%20the%20options%20above%20you,different%20set%20of%20configuration%20resources.&text=Command%2Dline%20arguments-,Note%3A,parameters%20in%20the%20Helm%20chart.).
- You can scale the ingress-nginx-controller deployment to 3 replicas, by using the following command : `kubectl scale deployment nginx-ingress-controller -n ingress-nginx --replicas=3`.

Let me know if you get any errors.  For more information refer to this [multiple ingress controller documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/multiple-ingress/#multiple-ingress-nginx-controllers).

Comment: I don't want to have many controllers, I just need to have many pods for the same controller. What about cookies, sessions etc ?

Comment: @Xavier123 : can you edit your question for what you are actually looking for?.  Whatever you have asked in the question i have provided the Solution.  You can also scale the pod replicas for the same controller by following this [doc](https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-scale-a-number-of-replicas-in-kubernetes) and command `$ kubectl scale deployment --replicas=3 <deployment_name>` or `kubectl scale deployments/<deployment_name> --replicas=<num_replicas>`

Comment: Regarding cookies and sessions, the Ingress-Nginx Controller itself does not store any state related to user sessions or cookies . If your application relies on session data, it is important to ensure that the session data is stored in a persistent storage solution, such as a database or a distributed cache. This way, even if a Pod is restarted or replaced, the new Pod can retrieve the session data from the persistent storage and continue the session seamlessly. Refer to this [sessions doc](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/affinity/cookie/) for more information.